# Is there a work-around for the Chrome error: "Require user gesture for beforeunload dialogs" during Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress, onbeforeunload

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808

**Require user gesture for beforeunload dialogs**

> The beforeunload dialog will only be shown if the frame attempting to
>   display it has received a user gesture or user interaction (or if any
>   embedded frame has received such a gesture). (There will be no change
>   to the dispatch of the beforeunload event, just a change to whether
>   the dialog is shown.)

Here is the problem we're running into. In our single page app, business rules dictate that we alert the user if they click the browser back button.

Which is what this code does below in our app.js:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', event => {
        event.returnValue = `Are you sure you want to leave?`;
    });
}
```

If the user navigates away on any page, the default alert box will pop up.

However in our Cypress tests we we have a `beforeEach` which goes back to the start of the app's flow before each test. This triggers the `beforeunload` event since we're leaving the page, but we don't see the alert, rather we get that chrome error:

> Require user gesture for beforeunload dialogs

Anyone run into this before or have a clue on a work around?

Only thing I can think off at the moment is to remove the `beforeEach` but then we will need individual tests for each thing we want to test. Rather than just a few page test files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were not able to disable the Chrome action for checking if the user has interacted so we came up with a simple work around:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
componentDidMount = () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBrowserBack);
    }
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
componentDidUpdate() {
    // If another error modal is up, DO NOT trigger the beforeunload alert
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && this.props.hasError) {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBrowserBack);
    }
}
```

Basically the beforeunload alert modal will now only display in the `production` env, and when we are cypress testing, they will not.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, though. You're just disabling it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's currently no way to interact with a website in a way that would qualify as a "user gesture", because Cypress currently uses programmatic browser APIs which Chrome doesn't consider as genuine user interaction (this will be possible when [native events](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/311) are implemented).

**EDIT:** re-reading the question, I'm not actually sure what you're after. If you really want to prevent the redirect, even during tests, then the following won't help. If you instead want to assert that the event was properly registered, and is doing what it's supposed to be doing, then see the below.

---

That being said, you don't need the `unload` event to be actually prevented (it's something you actually don't even want because then you'd need to manually confirm/cancel the dialog, which isn't possible ATM, although Cypress does that automatically in some cases). The callback is still called, and you can assert on that.

Thus, you can monkey-patch the event handler, cache the return value, and assert on it after the redirect:

```js
// cypress/support/index.js

const beforeUnloadRets = [];
// command used to assert on beforeunload event return values. Callback is
//  retried until it doesn't throw, and is invoked with the value
//  potentially-registered beforeunload handler return value. If handler was
//  registered, but didn't return anything (i.e. doesn't prevent the event),
//  the value is `null`. If no handler was registered, value is `undefined`.
Cypress.Commands.add('assertBeforeUnload', ( cb ) => {
  cy.wrap(null, { log: false }).should(() => cb(beforeUnloadRets.shift()));
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.on('window:before:load', ( win ) => {
    // monkey-patch `window.addEventListener` in case the `beforeunload` handler
    //  is registered using this API
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const _addEventListener = win.addEventListener;
    win.addEventListener = function (eventName, listener, ...rest) {
      if ( eventName === 'beforeunload' ) {
        const _origListener = listener;
        listener = (...args) => {
          const ret = _origListener(...args);
          beforeUnloadRets.push(ret === undefined ? null : ret);
          return ret;
        }
      }
      return _addEventListener.call(this, eventName, listener, ...rest);
    };

    // monkey-patch `window.onbeforeload` in case it's registered in that way
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    let _onbeforeunloadHandler;
    win.onbeforeunload = ( ev ) => {
      if ( _onbeforeunloadHandler ) {
        const ret = _onbeforeunloadHandler.call(win, ev);
        beforeUnloadRets.push(ret === undefined ? null : ret);
        return ret;
      }
    };
    Object.defineProperty(win, 'onbeforeunload', {
      set ( handler ) {
        _onbeforeunloadHandler = handler;
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Usage (note, for demonstration purposes, I register the `beforeunload` events inside the test, but in real scenario that's what your app will do):

```js
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {

    // page one. Register 1 beforeunload event, and prevent the unload event.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.visit('/a');

    cy.window().then( window => {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
        return 'one';
      });
    });

    // redirect to page two. Assert a prevented unload event.
    // Register another, but don't prevent unload.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.visit('/b');

    cy.assertBeforeUnload( ret => {
      expect(ret).to.eq('one');
    });

    cy.window().then( window => {
      // register, but don't prevent
      window.onbeforeunload = () => {};
    });

    // page three. Assert a non-prevented unload event. Register none.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.visit('/c');

    cy.assertBeforeUnload( ret => {
      // assert an event fired, but returned nothing (indicated by `null`)
      expect(ret).to.eq(null);
    });

    // page four. Assert no beforeunload event was fired.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.visit('/d');

    cy.assertBeforeUnload( ret => {
      expect(ret).to.eq(undefined);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that all seems too convoluted and unmaintainable :( checkout my answer, we're going to end up going with this.

Comment: It's not really that convoluted, I just implemented a thorough solution - you could reduce it further if using e.g. only `addEventListener` API.